# Can I use virtual machine running windows server 2012 to host sharepoint 2013

Tags: virtual-machine, sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012

I have windows 8 professional. and I want to create a virtual machine running windows server 2012 to host sharepoint server 2013 for development purposes. is there any limitations or recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a Stack Overflow question but since I've just done the same thing (Win 8 + Hyper-V/Win2012 + SharePoint 2013), I'll answer.

It is possible but Active Directory domain is required. So you will have to add DC role to the server or provision another VM acting as a domain controller.

Personally I found Windows Server 2012 to perform poorly in my virtual environment and I think I'll be going back to Win2008R2 + SP 2013 for development.